# Insert Each Cell in Header Row as An Individual Column BEFORE the data the header is above

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have an excel workbook where I need to take the header information, and insert it as a column.  My current set-up looks like this (except with data spanning much further to the right and down)
[image: Current Set Up]

And I need a macro that will format the data to look like this:
[image]

Is something like this possible with Excel 2013 VBA?

**EDIT**

I am not trying to transpose the header row.  I am trying to insert a blank column before the header and write the value to the newly inserted column.

Comment: would you mind embedding both images into the question itself? access is blocked on this network

Comment: How about a pivot table?

Comment: @Vityata - I did not know you could insert a row with a pivot table?  Mind showing an example?

Comment: @user1 - the images are embedded in the post?

Comment: @IcyPopTarts - assuming that you mean column, and not row - https://chandoo.org/wp/2015/04/16/how-to-insert-a-blank-column-in-pivot-table/

Comment: @Vityata - yes I mean column, good catch.  Is there a way to programmatically do this?  My header data extends from A1:XG1 and would take quite some time to manually key it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim c As Integer, i As Integer
Dim myheader As String

c = range("b2").End(xlToRight).Column
For i = 1 To c
    Columns(2 * i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    myheader = Cells(1, 2 * i).Value
    Cells(2, 2 * i + 1).Value = myheader
    Cells(2, 2 * i + 1).Select
    Selection.AutoFill destination:=range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, -1).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1))


Next i

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim c As Integer, i As Integer
Dim myheader As String

c = range("b2").End(xlToRight).Column
For i = 1 To c
    Columns(2 * i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    myheader = Cells(1, 2 * i + 1).Value
    Cells(2, 2 * i).Value = myheader
    Cells(2, 2 * i).Select
    Selection.AutoFill destination:=range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, -1).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1))
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: VERY close.  This inserts the header after the column of data.  Can it insert the header row before the column of data?

Comment: i'll change it in the originial  answer now